# Mechanism for verifying binary hash

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, libsodium, argon

I have a binary hash:

```
var hash = PasswordHash.ArgonHashBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwd), salt,StrengthArgon.Interactive)
```

Please tell me how can I convert byte array returned by method `ArgonHashBinary()` so that I can verify my password using `ArgonHashStringVerify()`.

P.S. there is no method that would allow me to verify password directly from binary hash i.e. there is no `ArgonHashBinaryVerify()` method.

Contrived example code:

```
var salt = PasswordHash.ArgonGenerateSalt();
var passwd = "ABCD";
var hash = PasswordHash.ArgonHashBinary(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwd), salt,StrengthArgon.Interactive);

if (ArgonHashStringVerify(hash, passwd))
{
    // password match
}
else 
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] and be clear as to what library you are using which provides `ArgonHashBinary`.

Comment: Added contrived example code for further elucidation.

Comment: Probably the .NET port of Libsodium (https://github.com/adamcaudill/libsodium-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pair `ArgonHashString()` with `ArgonHashStringVerify()`, like in the examples in the [unit test](https://github.com/adamcaudill/libsodium-net/blob/master/Tests/PasswordHashTest.cs):

```
const string PASSWORD = "gkahjfkjewrykjKJHKJHKJbhuiqyr  8923fhsjfkajwehkjg";
var hash = PasswordHash.ArgonHashString(PASSWORD);

Assert.IsTrue(PasswordHash.ArgonHashStringVerify(hash, PASSWORD));
```

Note that `ArgonHashBinary()` has another use: you use it to generate from a (potentially weak) password a (strong) encryption key that you'll use to encrypt something (a file for example). So it isn't used for password checking.